# Are mysql triggers atomic? Does this mysql trigger have concurrency issues?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, concurrency, triggers

I have created the following trigger to populate a field with a unique integer value.

I am using this in an InnoDB table and there is a UNIQUE key constraint on the field.

Is it possible that two concurrent inserts produce the same value and due to the unique constraint one of them fails, or are triggers "atomic"?

Are there any other issues with this code that I may not have thought of?

Is there a better whay to get the behaviour I want? Maby some soft of isomorphism on the auto increment value?

```
CREATE TRIGGER `generate_customer_id` BEFORE INSERT ON `users`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
DECLARE i INT;
DECLARE duplicate INT DEFAULT 1;
DECLARE tries INT DEFAULT 0;
WHILE duplicate > 0 DO
    SET tries = tries + 1;
    IF tries > 100 THEN
       SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
            SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'no customer id found after 100 tries', MYSQL_ERRNO = 1001;
    END IF;

    SET i = ROUND((RAND() * (999999999-100000000))+100000000);
    SET duplicate = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE customer_id = i);      
END WHILE;

SET NEW.customer_id = i;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible alternative to the random number generator is to create a `customer_ids` table with an auto_increment primary key - create a new row in the table to create a unique customer_id for the `users` table

Comment: you mean essentially create a mapping table from auto_increment_id to random_number and pre populate it?

Comment: @TheSurrican Yeah, something like `select id from customer_ids where is_used = 0 order by rand() limit 1` should minimize the number of collisions